# Inequality Conditions

Tags: functions, inequality, polynomials

Let $h_{k}(x)>0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{l}h_{k}(x)=1$ (Here, $h_{k}(x)$ are some continuous functions).

Is the statement below correct or not?

$f_{k}(x)<0$ when $g_{k}(x)=0$, $\forall x \neq 0$, $k=1,...,l$

is the sufficient condition for

$\sum_{k=1}^{l}h_{k}(x)f_{k}(x)<0$ when $\sum_{k=1}^{l}h_{k}(x)g_{k}(x)=0$,$\forall x\neq0$

Here, $f_{k}(x)$ and $g_{k}(x)$ are polynomials.

Please give me some enlightment.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum^l_{k=1}h_kf_k=h_1f_1+h_2f_2+\ldots+h_lf_l$$
Since $h_k>0$ and $f_k<0$ when $g_k=0$, $$h_1f_1+h_2f_2+\ldots+h_lf_l<0$$
I.e.,
$$\sum^l_{k=1}h_kf_k<0\mbox{ when $g_k=0$, i.e., when $\sum^l_{k=1}h_kg_k=h_1g_1+h_2g_2+\ldots h_lg_l=0\forall x\neq0$}$$
So, 
$$\boxed{\sum^l_{k=1}h_kf_k<0\mbox{ }\mathbf{ iff }\mbox{ }\sum^l_{k=1}h_kg_k=0\forall x\neq0}$$
So the sufficiency condition is satisfied (by the definition of "iff").

Comment: I have two questions for your answer.

1. If we use "iff" it means necessary and sufficient condition?

2. Whether the condition still hold for $h$ as a non-linear function?

Thank you very much for the answer anyway,,,I really appreciate it.

Comment: @mathNewbie89 "Iff" means $A\implies B$, $B\implies A$. So, iff does mean necessary and sufficient. For 2), note that nowhere in my answer did I assume that $h$ is linear. So, the condition holds $h$ continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much, for your answer. Actually what I want to ask is if we can find a set of $x$ that guarantee $f_{k}<0$ when $g_{k}=0$, does that mean that set of $x$ will also guarantee $\sum_{k=1}^{l} h_{k}f_{k}<0$ when $\sum_{k=1}^{l} h_{k}g_{k}=0$?

To generalize my question, when $A'$ is the sufficient condition of $A$ and $B'$ is the sufficient condition of $B$, Does $A'$ when $B'$ is also the sufficient condition for $A$ and $B$? 

I am sorry asking so much question (or may be the same question again and again), I still feel something is off. Many thanks in advance.